Don't get Flutter trace of SDK crash on Crashlytics dashboard
In my Flutter app I use a native SDK. I am trying to integrate crashlytics for Android module. It is working as expected and since the SDK provides symbols, I upload it using from CI
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app=FIREBASE_APP_ID PATH/TO/SYMBOLS
and I see readable SDK crashes on crashlytics. But the problem is I don't see Flutter stack trace (origin) of the crash. It shows unsymbolicated SDK crash and in bottom (on different threads) I only see
libc.so   (Missing BuildId 84a42637b3a421b801818f5793418fca)

I do not have any fancy configuration for crashlytics.
build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
}

dependencies {
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.7.0"))

    // Add the dependencies for the Crashlytics and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk")
    ...
}

settings.gradle
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '8.7.2' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "3.0.2" apply false
}

